# Solidity Js, on function get i get an error as "TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity

`

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract{

string value;
constructor() public   {
    value = "MyValue";
}
function get() public returns(string)  {
    return value;
}

function set(string memory _value) public  {
    value = _value;
}


}`
```

on function get i get an error as TypeError: Data location must be "memory" or "calldata" for return parameter in function, but none was given. i couldnt solve it because the "value" variable is already identified it doesn neew to be memoried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`string` is a reference type, so you need to specify its [data location](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.15/types.html#data-location). In this case, the value is loaded from storage to memory, and then returned from the `memory`.

```
function get() public returns(string memory)  {
    return value;
}
```